# Jenkins fails deploying big file to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, wix, windows-installer, maven-3, artifactory

We have a Jenkins job that builds some MSI files and deploys it to our local Artifactory instance. As recently the file size of this artifact changed from 153.30 MB to 186.60 MB the job failed and didn't deploy anything.

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing artifact to Artifactory: ...file-SNAPSHOT.msi.
```

Caused by: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

I found a similar issue here:
*[Cannot copy large Artifacts [502 Bad Gateway]](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/cannot-copy-large-artifacts-502-bad-gateway-702710321.html)*

This is the only job/project having this issue.

Artifactory is configured to allow uploads up to 500 MB.

Any ideas?

Comment: In Jenkins main system configuration page, under the advanced section of Artifactory server configuration. Raise the "Connection Timeout" to something like 500 seconds and give it a try

Comment: I know that config in Jenkins and already have 300s there configured but thx for the tipp.

Comment: No brother, will share your question with some colleagues who are still into jenkins, shall let you know ASAP.

Comment: Hi, Artifactory does not return "Unexpected HTTP status code: HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway". This is usually coming from a proxy server. Do you have proxy server defined between Artifactory and Jenkins, if so can you look at the logs of this proxy server and write here what you see?